# Better way to handle default profile image through javascript

Tags: javascript, image

```
var imgRoot='forum/attachments/users/';

<img 
 src="../employees/attachments/users/username_xyz.png" 
 onerror='this.src=imgRoot+"no_profile_pic.png" '
/>
```

I have to show user profile images (which are not set in db ) , just  plain upload to a pre-defined directory , spaces replaced with underscores in username e.g user name is 'A B C' , we expect an image A_B_C.png. Issue arises when there is no image for user , we have to show default image , as shown above by adding a onerror event to load default image .

Is there any better way to handle this ? We do not know in advance that if user has profile picture upload or not. Another annoyance is that firebug reports network error when it does not finds user profile image before loading fallback default profile image.

Comment: Can you add server side page that will check given path if exists or not and return an answer? This way you can use AJAX to load the images.

Comment: I think you are suggesting to use src="profile_image.php?username" or sth like this ? But am curious about handling this within the scope of js and image node . To you question yes I can add a php page or call and ajax request .

Comment: Yes this would be a good way. How your current code looks like? Can you post it so we see the bigger picture here?

Comment: its almost js , consuming json data, above is the total code for single image

Answer (score 1):

I would have the server respond with an http `302` redirect to a default profile image url when the file is not found. Most web servers can do this without any code, just a config file.

*Edit:* Since you're using Apache, here's what you need to do:

1. Make sure mod_rewrite is installed.
2. If you're going to use an `.htaccess` file, make sure `AllowOverride On` is set for the target directory.
3. Edit your `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` file.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^.*$ /anonymous.jpg [L,R=302]
   ```

There are a lot of quirks with Apache config, so your config might have to be slightly different.

Comment: .htaccess ? some details plz

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: on localhost this just fails , instead of adding http://localhost/~username , it adds http://localhost/users/useranme/anoymous.jpg. It would be excellent if it picks the url base correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment until now. It should redirect to `http://localhost/anonymous.jpg`, unless the file exists. Try testing in a new folder to see if it's something with your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Javascript to preload the image. When the image loads, attach it. If it fails do something else, like providing a fallback one. Here you have a JS code snippet showing a possible solution:

```
/**
 * Tries to load an image and renders a fallback image if it fails.
 * @param {string} srcImage The source of the image to load.
 * @param {string} srcFallback The source of the fallback image.
 */
function loadImageOrFallback(srcImage, srcFallback) {
  var image = new Image(),
      timerFallback = null,
      hasRenderedFallbackImage = false;

  image.onload = function() {
    if (timerFallback !== null) {
      clear(timerFallback);
    }

    if (hasRenderedFallbackImage) {
       // replace the fallback image
    } else {
      // append image to wherever you want
    }
  };

  image.src = srcImage;

  // since there is no way to detect an error when preloading the image,
  // you can use a timeout function (here we are waiting 2 seconds)

  timerFallback = setTimeout(function() {
    var fallbackImage = new Image();
    fallbackImage.src = srcFallback;

    // append fallbackImage to wherever you want

    hasRenderedFallbackImage = true;

  }, 2000);
}

loadImageOrFallback('A_B_C.png', 'fallback.png');
```

Checking this using JavaScript follows a try-and-error approach. The timeout introduces some delay too. If you can detect this situation server-side it would be much better.

Note that there is a chance that the image gets loaded after rendering the fallback image. That is why we store that the fallback image has been appended, and check its value in the `onload` callback.

I have prepared [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pYge/) that shows how you would use it.

Comment: I better handle this server-side

Answer (score 0):

You can get the web application to check the filesystem and see if the file exists. Dont know what your web app is built in. PHP example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Doing it in JS is hacky. Its always going to try to load the image.

Comment: thanks, php is not a option here I am getting a json object with user names using that json object I have to construct profile images urls